# Composer install failing

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sylius

I was given a project to work on, and to get it set up I am trying to use composer install to get all my dependencies install and working.  The issue is when I try to run composer install, I get the following errors:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sylius/sales-bundle 0.1.x-dev could not be found.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for sylius/cart-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sylius/cart-bundle[dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: sylius/resource-bundle[v0.3.0, v0.1.0].
    - sylius/cart-bundle dev-master requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.3.* -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[v0.3.0].
    - Installation request for sylius/resource-bundle 0.1.*@dev -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[v0.1.0].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
```

The composer.json file looks like this:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/twig": "dev-master",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.1.*@dev",
        "liip/doctrine-cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "apy/datagrid-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
        "bcc/cron-manager-bundle": "dev-master",
        "craue/formflow-bundle": "dev-master",
        "craue/config-bundle": "dev-master",
        "ddeboer/data-import": "dev-master",
        "phpexcel/phpexcel": "1.7.6",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
        "elnur/blowfish-password-encoder-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "1.3.1",
        "friendsofsymfony/message-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest": "0.8.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "frosas/base-url-bundle": "1.*@dev",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/serializer": "0.11.*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.11.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*@dev",
        "jms/debugging-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/job-queue-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/payment-core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*@dev",
        "jms/twig-js": "dev-master",
        "jms/twig-js-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.2.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lexik/mailer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lexik/maintenance-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lexik/form-filter-bundle": "dev-master",
        "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "1.3.x-dev",
        "Trsteel/ckeditor-bundle": "dev-master",
        "velvel/report-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/jquery-bundle": "1.8.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/exporter": "1.1.0",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-extensions": "1.0.0",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "1.0.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
        "sylius/blogger-bundle": "0.1.x-dev",
        "sylius/cart-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sylius/categorizer-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.1.*@dev",
        "sylius/sales-bundle": "0.1.x-dev",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "2.1.x-dev as dev-master",
        "pagerfanta/pagerfanta": "1.0.*@dev",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle": "*",
        "whiteoctober/breadcrumbs-bundle": "dev-master",
        "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle": "*",
        "nelmio/js-logger-bundle": "~1.0",
        "nelmio/security-bundle": "~1.0",
        "mtdowling/cron-expression": "1.0.x",
        "liip/imagine-bundle": "dev-master",
        "elao/web-profiler-extra-bundle" : "2.1.*@dev",
        "elink/payment-slimcd-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
        "punkave/symfony2-file-uploader-bundle": "dev-master",
        "leek/git-debug-bundle": "2.0.*@dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
```

The project is using Symfony as a framework, and everytime I think I have a fix, it causes other issues.  I have been banging my head for over an hour trying to get this sorted out.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of dependencies. Doesn't your application has too many jobs ? You may consider deleting some. Like `jms/twig-js` since you have `jms/twig-js-bundle` which have a dependency with `jms/twig-js`. Same for `jms/serializer`, `knp/menu`...

Comment: I didn't write this, it was given to me in a github repo, I was just added as a member of the development team, I will tell them and attempt to clean it up though

Comment: Thanks for your help, cleaned it up and not it works.  this is my first project using composer so this was all new to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should replace your line including sales-bundle by : 
"sylius/sales-bundle": "0.2.*@dev"

check the packagist website and enter the name of your bundles when you have problems. It will show you dependencies between bundles and what are the versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to packagist website, much help